# Application of Stokes Theorem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

I need help with the following demo:

Show that for a steerable surface $ \Sigma $ with $\partial \Sigma=C$ an oriented curve has to

$\int_{C} (f \nabla g+g \nabla f ) d \vec{r}=0$

for any functions f, g of class $ C^{2} $ with open domain containing $ \Sigma $

What I have tried was with conservative fields since the integrand is equal to $ \nabla (fg) $, but the conditions that are put in the conservative field theorem are different, so I think it is not right.

Comment: You certainly do not need the $C^2$ hypothesis, but you can prove the theorem you have in mind on conservative force fields *when you have a closed curve that bounds a surface* by applying Stokes's Theorem. But all you *need* is $C^1$ and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (so Stokes's Theorem one dimension lower).

Comment: but the statement does not say that C is a closed curve, it only tells us oriented

Comment: If it's the boundary of an (orientable) surface $\Sigma$ (with boundary), then it's necessarily a closed curve.

Comment: Oh, cierto, then it would be a direct application of the conservative field theorem, right?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: @VividD: I'm not sure why you're making irrelevant edits, when the question is done with. And if you're going to edit, why not fix "steerable"? I think bringing old questions back to the "top" of the heap for purely cosmetic reasons is a BAD use of edits and should be discouraged.

Comment: @Ted I limit my edits to just small fraction of time, so they should not be nuisance. I am sure that the correct spelling of "theorem" is important for a math Q/A forum like this. You can sacrifice a little bit of your convenience for that. :)

Comment: @VividD: My point then is that you should do a better job of editing. Fix words that are not English. Otherwise, why bother?