# Closed curve and bouder

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

could you help me with the following, please:

If a curve C is the border of a surface $\Sigma$ then C is closed?

My intuition says yes, but how could it be formally demonstrated?

Comment: How do you define border?

Comment: I define boundary as the lock of the surface minus its interior

Comment: And what is the lock of a surface?

Comment: I do not know if I explain, but my question comes from the following post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3673689/application-of-stokes-teorem?noredirect=1#comment7549979_3673689 I would like to apply theo.  of conservative fields, but I don't know if the hypotheses are equivalent to C being closed, or do you know of any way to prove the post?